# Integer parsing

Tags: c#

I need to write a validation for a textbox which value is < = 2147483647

my code is something like:

```
Textbox1.Text = "78987162789"

if(Int32.Parse(Textbox1.text) > 2147483647)
{
  Messagebox("should not > ")
}
```

I am getting error message something like: `value is too small or too big for Int`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Consider using constants, such as int32.MaxValue instead of hardcoding them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method which is better for that purpose.

```
int Val;
bool ok = Int32.TryParse (Textbox1.Text, out Val);
if (!ok) { ... problem occurred ... }
```

Comment: @paxdiablo  - i want to up vote also but i don't have points.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Integers are stored using 32 bits, so you only have 32 bits with which to represent your data; 31 once you take into account negative numbers. So numbers that are larger than `2^31 - 1` cannot be represented as integers. That number is 2147483647. So since 78987162789 > 2147483648, it cannot convert it to an integer.

Try using a `long` instead.

**Edit:**

Of course, `long` only works up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (2 ^ 63 - 1), so you may end up in the same problem. So, as other people have suggested, use Int32.TryParse - if that fails, you can assume it's not a number, or it's bigger than your limit.

Comment: And when the user enters 3742643647634537643465346534634535453563453563635353 into the textbox?

Comment: I hope that randomly entered number is greater than (2^63)-1 or I'm going to look pretty foolish :-)

Comment: Hah.  Point made though -- there's no getting away from not handling inputs that are invalid or not a number.  That said, this was the first answer to say use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: I think you meant Int32.TryParse, otherwise you'll have to have *another* check to ensure the number is less that the limit specified.

Comment: Its heaps longer : 4587566320000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

```
Int64 result;
if (!Int64.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, out result))
{
    // The value is not a number or cannot be stored in a 64-bit integer.
}
else if (result > (Int64)Int32.MaxValue)
{
    // The value cannot be stored in a 32-bit integer.
}
```

Comment: What's the value of the `else if` condition?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Chaos: I think he means, "what's the added value of performing that additional check?"  Also, note that a successful Int64.TryParse does not guarantee that the value is a number, as your comment suggests.

Comment: nm, I'm a moron that can't read... I missed the `!` in front of int64.TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because 78987162789 is greater than 2^31, so it's too big for an Int32.  As suggested, use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method, and only proceed if it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event.

```
private void textbox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Int64 numberEntered = Int64.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (numberEntered > 2147483647)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("You have to enter number up to 2147483647");
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("You need to enter a valid integer");
    }
}



    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        // 
        // more code
        // 
        this.Textbox1.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.textbox1_Validating);
    }
```